# Conditional transformRequest in $resource.$save

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I use `$resource` extensively. I would like to be able to set the `transformRequest` property on $save on some routes/resources but not on others. How can I do that?

In the `$resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);` definition, you can only set the `transformRequest` on the custom actions, not the `$save` method.

In the `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest` you can't determine which route/method you are on as you don't have access to the url/path, only the params data.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
    return {
        "request": function (config) {
            if (config.method === "POST" && new RegExp("{myregexhere}").test(config.url)) {
                // keep only the default
                config.transformRequest.length = 1;
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```